# Unable to open file object created in Django

Tags: python, django, apache, beautifulsoup

I'm developing an application that runs on an Apache server with Django framework. My current script works fine when it runs on the local desktop (without Django). The script downloads all the images from a website to a folder on the desktop. However, when I run the script on the server a file object is just create by Django that apparently has something in it (should be google's logo), however, I can't open up the file. I also create an html file, updated image link locations, but the html file gets created fine, I'm assuming because it's all text, maybe? I believe I may have to use a file wrapper somewhere, but I'm not sure. Any help is appreciated, below is my code, Thanks!

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import urlparse
from urllib2 import urlopen
from urllib import urlretrieve
import os
import sys
import zipfile
from django.core.servers.basehttp import FileWrapper

def getdata(request):
out = 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\images'
if request.GET.get('q'):
    #url = str(request.GET['q'])
    url = "http://google.com"
    soup = bsoup(urlopen(url))
    parsedURL = list(urlparse.urlparse(url))

    for image in soup.findAll("img"):
        print "Old Image Path: %(src)s" % image
    #Get file name
    filename = image["src"].split("/")[-1]
    #Get full path name if url has to be parsed
    parsedURL[2] = image["src"]
    image["src"] = '%s\%s' % (out,filename)
    print 'New Path: %s' % image["src"]
    #       print image
    outpath = os.path.join(out, filename)

    #retrieve images
    if image["src"].lower().startswith("http"):
        urlretrieve(image["src"], outpath)
    else:
        urlretrieve(urlparse.urlunparse(parsedURL), out) #Constructs URL            from tuple (parsedURL)

    #Create HTML File and writes to it to check output (stored in same directory).
    html = soup.prettify("utf-8")
    with open("output.html", "wb") as file:
        file.write(html)


else:
    url = 'You submitted nothing!'

return HttpResponse(url)
```

Comment: Additonal note to share that may be helpful: Under the properties for the file, windows lists the attribute A, which means that windows recognizes it as an archive file from what I understand.

Comment: There are multiple factors involved here. For one I am not sure google would serve the standard page . Google might be serving different things for different user agents. Also you say that these are archived  , I am not sure but you should see the content headers , you might be able to find the encoding and it should be gzip or something

Comment: I just used google because it contains only one image on the page to parse. I tried using 7-zip to open up the file, but I get an error message saying it is unable to open up the file as an archive.

Comment: I am not really an expert on windows but you can check what kind of file it is by looking at the file header . On linux libmagic can do that. You can check this out https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic

Comment: If I view the file in Notepad++, the first line is %PNG, which seems right as the google logo is a png file. However, the windows just doesn't recognize the file image file when I use Django to download the image onto my local desktop. Without Djano incorporated, the script works fine.

Comment: I just opened up the file with paint and it opened up and showed google's logo...I will have to look more into how Djano handles file uploads. Thanks for the help though dusual.

Comment: Well I don't see any file uploads in your question. By the way if this sufficiently answers your question I will like to submit this as an answer

Comment: I meant download, the images are downloaded to the local computer using the beautiful soup library. This hasn't answered my question, as something needs to be done to the File Object on the django side to allows windows to recognize it, something with File Wrapper as I previously mentioned I think.

Comment: you can try using python-magic as I mention on top to recognize the file type and do what you need to get windows to recongnize the files. However do you plan to serve these files . If you can explain exactly what your end goal is it might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem had to do with storing the files on the desktop. I stored the files in the DJango workspace folder, changed the paths, and it worked for me.